# Why does this not work? What have I done wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why doesn't the paragraph below work?

```
<body onload="x()" background=" http://theworldsbestever.s3.amazonaws.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/tumblr_inline_mi17k7Afai1qz4rgp.gif"> <font size="32%"><h1 style="font-family: Verdana; color: red; text-align: center"><u>How long is your text?<u></font>

</h1>
<br>
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <input style="text-align: center;" id="input1" maxlength="6" placeholder="Enter Some Text">
  <br><br>
        <button type="button" onclick="x()">Submit</button>
</div>
<p id="textLength2" style="color: white; text-align: center; font-family: verdana;"></p>
<script>
    function x() {
        var textLength = document.getElementById("input1");
        var textLength = textLength.length;
        document.getElementById("textLength2").innerHTML = textLength;
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: what do you mean doesn't work?

Comment: the paragraph below is supposed to return the length of the input field, but it doesnt work

Comment: "Can you find the bug" questions [are not good questions for Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253787/are-there-legitimate-fix-my-code-questions?cb=1#253788). Make sure you provide a brief, but **specific statement of the problem**, telling us precisely what is wrong. "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement.

Answer (score 5):

`document.getElementById("input1")` gives you an input element, not a string. You need to read its `value` property.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I understood.

```
 function x() {
        var textLength = document.getElementById("input1").value.length;
        document.getElementById("textLength2").innerHTML = textLength;
    }
```

Comment: input elements don't have (sensible) `innerHTML` values, they are defined as `EMPTY` so can't have child nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I share this code without errors.

```
    <html>

<body onload="x()" 
</h1>
<br>
<div style="text-align: center;">
        <input style="text-align: center;" id="input1" maxlength="6" placeholder="Enter Some Text"> </input>
            <br><br>
        <button type="button" onclick="return x()">Submit</button>
</div>
<p id="textLength2" style="color: white; text-align: center; font-family: verdana;"></p>
<script>
    function x() {
        var text ;
        text = document.getElementById('input1').value;
        console.log(text);
        var long = text.length;

        document.getElementById("textLength2").innerHTML = text;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```